# HTML で JavaScript を読み込む際にエラー Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, html

下記のようなファイル配置で「Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND」というエラーが出ます。

調べたところ、主にファイルの配置やファイルパスの設定が間違っているとのことでしたが、windowsPCだとエラーが発生せず（意図した動作を確認）、MacPCだと発生します。（ファイル配置はHTMLと同じ階層）
利用ブラウザは両方ともGoogle Chrome（最新）です。
OS違いで何か（例えば、HTML側のjsファイルのパス等）書き方を変える必要があるのでしょうか？
打開策が見つからないのでよろしくお願いします。

テストフォルダ
　→htmlファイル
　→jsファイル

htmlファイル

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsファイル名"></script>
</head>
<body style="background:#333333">
<canvas id="main" width="720" height="540"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: 質問文では `src="jsファイル名"` とされていますが、ここが肝心のエラー個所なので、伏せたりせず実際の記述を公開できないでしょうか？

Comment: Windows とMac ではファイルのパスの扱いが違う点に注意してください。

Comment: 「windowsPCだとエラーが発生せず（意図した動作を確認）、MacPCだと発生します。」というのは、webサーバーの話ではなくローカルでそれぞれのPC上でhtmlをChromeで開いたときの話でしょうか？

Comment: マルチポスト https://qiita.com/togehome/questions/8d90f51ba25b6bc95810

Comment: sayuri様　失礼致しました。実際はmain.jsです。

Comment: merino様　ローカルでそれぞれのPC上でhtmlをChromeで開いたときの話です。

Comment: – 
cubick♦様の言う通りでした！

Comment: 皆様、ご教授頂きありがとうございました！

Comment: 何が「言う通り」だったのでしょうか? もし解決したのでしたら、問題と解決策をご自身で回答として書いていただけると助かります。

Comment: 失礼いたしました。HTML２行目について、Windowsだとディレクトリを./main.jsもしくはmain.jsで通るのですが、MACだと./main.jsしか認識しないことがわかりました。そのため、MACでは省略形での記述は控えた方が良さそうです。